# Get access to Views in another layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I get reference to the TextViews, for example, if I didn't set layout as a content view?

I'm using TabHost to switch between Activities:

```
public class TimerResultsActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initTabs();

        TextView resultsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        resultsText.setText("test");
    }
```

`...`

"textView1" has added to one of tabs, but hasn't declared in the main.xml.
How can I change a text on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a reference to the base of the layout that it *is* declared in. Then you can use the `findViewById()` method of the `ViewGroup` it belongs to.

```
TextView resultsText = (TextView)myTab.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
...
```

Comment: Also have to inflate the layout.